# Check serial port information/description to verify right port

Tags: c++, c, arduino, serial-port

I am working under Linux, I try to connect an Arduino Mega, if I have no other device connected its port is usually /dev/ttyAMC0, the problem is that sometimes it is /dev/ttyAMC1 /dev/ttyAMC2.... So I wonder if the port has some kind of description or information of the device it is connected to, so when I open a port I can check that it is an Arduino connection and not other device. I work with C and C++

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Not it's not possible unless the connected system have some program or code that will send such "identification" if requested. The serial hardware itself is pretty "dumb", and contains no intelligence what so ever.

Comment: Usually, serial ports / devices do not have this kind of information. There is no ID or anything like that (as with USB), unless you explicitly program it in.

Comment: ummm, that is a pitty, thanks a lot for your answers!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a different approach than you suggested (but far more common), but you can write a UDEV rule so that the Mega is always attached to a port you can name such as /dev/ArduinoMega. Depending on how you set the UDEV rule you can have this be the case for any Arduino Mega, or only for one particular Mega.

There is an excellent guide to doing this that I've been using for ages that is available [here](http://hintshop.ludvig.co.nz/show/persistent-names-usb-serial-devices/).

Comment: Please copy the essential parts of the linked article into the text of your answer because links can break in the future.

Comment: I saw that article and I have tried it and it works, the problem is that with some devices the Serial Number I get is pretty strange and is not recognized by the udev rules, I dont know why, when I have time I will post an example

Answer (score 0):

You could have the arduino periodically "chirp" whenever it has serial connected ie send out an id string in ascii that will let your computer side program know that it is the correct device.  A different style of the same idea would be to have a canned command response where the arduino monitors the port and sends a known response when given a proper command string.  These both seem obvious and simple, so I feel that this is not what you are looking for...